# Using multiple Kinetic.Tween

Tags: kineticjs, tween, motion

in my app, i have many pawns that i want to move at the same time. I created my pawns and I use an instance "Kinetic.Tween" for every pawn: this approach is ok with Firefox, Chrome, but when i use my app on mobile device, I've been experience some really hard lag. Now  I'm thinking to replace my multiple instances of "Kinetic.Tween" with only one instance of "Kinetic.Animation". Before we begin I would like to ask:

1) for you, what I want to do, is it ok?
2) Exist a plugin that manages multiple "tween"?

Thank you 
Giancarlo

Answer (score 0):

I resolved now I use GreenSock Animation for KineticJS plugin
http://forums.greensock.com/topic/7016-animating-kineticjs-objects/